# Heat transfer in open equalization tank

Tags: heat-transfer, chemical-engineering, pipelines, convection

I have to cool waste water in equalization tank (open tank) from 60 C to 30 C.
Here is the information about the waste water:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqiSG.png

and here is the tank dimension:
L = 13,4 m
W = 11,4 m
H = 4,85 m

Cooling medium is RO water with inlet temp 28 C and flowrate 8m3/h
I totally confuse to solve this problem.
Because i don't know exactly the composition in waste water so i assume it's water (based on the majority composition).

I think i'm gonna design RO water inside pipe with circulate configuration inside equalization tank.
I calculate heat transfer with internal force convection method (since water is flowing inside pipe) and natural convection method (between water surface and ambient air). I assume that the tank wall is insulated with no radiation. I also assume that waste water volume as full as tank dimension.

From that calculation method i neglect the influence (maybe if it'll be significant) of the pipe configuration, about bending, the distance from each pipe. I think there must be an influenced on it, it could be about heat transfer efficiency and how well the cooling distribution is.

How do you think about the way i solve this problem?

Sorry for my bad english, if there's something sounds rude and offensive.

**Updated info:**

This is the way i try to solve this problem.

I calculate the pipe length required to cool fluid inside open tank. With the data i had shown yesterday. I assume that no radiation, tank wall is insulated because the outer surface doesn't contact with ambient air, heat from ambient air is negligible (no longer using natural convection).
My reference book is from Heat and Mass Transfer Fundamental and Application, Yunus A. Cengel and Afshin J. GhajarGhajar,  in chapter 8.

You can see my calculation and the pipe sketch inside the tank in a file I’ve attached below

With those data i did my calculation based on forced convection of fluid inside pipe. I also assume the pipe diameter with 2 simulations scenario using 10 inch and 1 inch pipe. I notice that the result doesn’t make sense. The calculation using 1 inch pipe has smaller pipe length compare with 10 inch pipe. The way i calculate is from the heat required from the tank then I assign it as heat for force calculation inside pipe (because Qin = Qout). I assume that outlet temperature of pipe is equal with desired tank (30 C)

Based on the Nusselt number (Nu) of each simulation, the smaller pipe has the greater value than the larger pipe. That’s because the flowrate in smaller pipe is higher, so that Re (Reynold Number) will be increased as well. With the higher Re can cause hl (convective heat transfer coefficient) higher too which will result to lower heat transfer surface contact. This is also applied on larger pipe with opposite result.

The focus here is to cool the tank. According to my understanding, to cool the tank with those data, the smaller pipe should has longer pipe length than the larger pipe. Based on my calculation, the pipe length for 1 inch is around 966 m, while for 10 inch is around 6810 m, so from this it’s likely the pipe diameter is proportional with the pipe length. I think that’s impossible, imagine if using pipe diameter closer to 0 it's likely that the pipe length is also very short. With short pipe length and smaller diameter, it’s not enough to cool the tank.

But that’s what happened to my calculation. My guess is because the way I calculate is (maybe unconsciously) focusing on heating the pipe from 28 to 30. But I don’t know, I don’t have any idea why this can be wrong.

So what do you guys think?
*I try to simulate the calculation without natural convection, when the force convection one is already clear I will try to consider this too.
*Let me know if there is something still unclear for you, I will try my best to make it more understandable

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1TlV9CxFvpx_A6q1GA0PLx6JI4_u5TXQC

Comment: I am not sure what the question is. Could you provide more details about intended solution (a simple sketch) and information about heat transfer coefficients you have used?

Comment: @TomášLétal here is my calculation, i put in on this link. 
     https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1TlV9CxFvpx_A6q1GA0PLx6JI4_u5TXQC              Please kindly check out again my question because i add more information about this

Comment: Try to incorporate how the cooling temperature in the pipe changes as you go further from the start.